# Upgrade Spring Data Neo4j to 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, neo4j

I am trying to upgrade Spring Data Neo4j from 2.2.1 to 3.0.0, everything is fine except one error in root-context.xml configuration file.

Error message is:

```
 Error occured processing XML 'tried to access method org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/
 annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinition;)V from class org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider'. See Error Log for more details
```

The pom.xml file as following:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version><!-- 4.0.2RELEASE -->
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.12</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.springdata.neo4j>3.0.1.RELEASE</org.springdata.neo4j><!-- 3.0.1.RELEASE -->
    <org.springsecurity-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
    <jackson.version>2.3.0</jackson.version>
    <drools.version>6.0.1.Final</drools.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Joda Time Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>               
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cn.co.tory</groupId>
      <artifactId>cats-integration</artifactId>
      <version>[1.0,1.1)</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springdata.neo4j}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springdata.neo4j}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

root-context.xml configuration file as following:

```
<!-- Activate Spring Data Neo4j repository support -->
<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" base-package="cn.co.tory"/>
<neo4j:repositories base-package="cn.co.tory"></neo4j:repositories>
<bean id="graphDatabaseService"
    class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
    destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${neo4j.storeDirectory}" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Same thing happens when you use SDN 3.0.1.RELEASE?

Comment: Check http://blog.neo4j.org/2014/03/spring-data-neo4j-progress-update-sdn-3.html also. It seems that you still need to specify the "basePackage" which is a new requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Same problem with SDN 3.0.1 but different error message: AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(…) is not public! Make sure you're using Spring 3.2.5 or better. The class was loaded from %s.

Comment: add `base-package` for your domain entities for `neo4j:config` and use `storeDir` attribute instead of the `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` bean.

Comment: I made change root-context.xml file as above but still got the error: AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(…) is not public!

Answer (score 2):

You should use Spring version 3.2.5 or higher.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryComponentProvider.java

> AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(…) is not public! Make sure you're using Spring 3.2.5 or better. The class was loaded from %s.

Comment: Indeed, so there's no need to specify your own specific version. SDN uses 3.2.8.RELEASE at the moment.

Comment: I guess that the OP uses org.springframework-version property to define same version for all spring dependencies (e.g. web-mvc).

Comment: Can you list your complete dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree`? Perhaps a version mismatch? Also in SDN 3.0 / Neo4j 2.0 there is no public constructor for EmbeddedGraphDatabase anymore, but I added a `GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean` instead.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I added the complete dependency tree already. the error message is AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(…) is not public! Make sure you're using Spring 3.2.5 or better. The class was loaded from file:/home/may/Development Tools/eclipse/
 plugins/org.springframework.context_4.0.0.20130829-M3.jar.: 
 org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition)

Comment: You need to post output of *mvn dependency:tree* command. What you posted is your pom.xml, not actually resolved dependecies (which are be different as org.springframework.context_4.0.0.20130829-M3.jar suggests).